# how to calculate percentage changes across 2 columns in a dataframe using pct_change in Python without knowing column name but position in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get percentage difference between columns `Value1` and `Value2` and provide my result in the specific position between those columns. I don't know the name of any of those columns, so I have to calculate my value knowing only their positions Value1 = position 2 and Value2 = position 3.

**my.csv**

```
ID   Name   Value1    Value2    Value3
1    ACME     100       150       300
```

desired output:

```
ID   Name   Value1    %difference    Value2    Value3
1    ACME     100          50%         150       300
```

my code doesn't seem to work:

```
result = df[df.iloc[:, 2], df.iloc[:, 3]].pct_change(axis=1)[df.iloc[:, 3]
df[3,'% difference', result]
```

Could someone help me with this please? thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.columns` will give you list of column names you can reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try if this suits you:

```
result = df.iloc[:,[2,3]].pct_change(axis=1).iloc[:,1]
df.insert(3,"% difference",result) # inplace
df

    ID  Name    Value1  % difference    Value2  Value3
0   1   ACME    100     0.5             150     300
```